# How does named container know each other's ip address in docker user created bridged network?

Tags: docker, docker-network

```
docker network create --driver bridge network1
docker run -itd --name docker1 --network network1 busybox
docker run -itd --name docker2 --network network1 busybox
docker exec -it docker1 /bin/bash
```

now in docker1, I can ping docker2

```
/ # ping docker2
PING docker2 (172.19.0.3): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.19.0.3: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.056 ms
```

I thought this entry is added in /etc/hosts, but it is not

```
/ # cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
172.19.0.2      841c0dc99115
```

How does docker1 know docker2's ip address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker resolves names through internal dns server which is used by the Docker Daemon you can check the dns adress by  `cat /etc/resolv.conf` to understand more you can read [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/configure-dns/)